# Pass the information of one form to another

Tags: c#, forms, c#-4.0

I have create a simple user registration form in C#.net (windows application) which have DateTimePicker control, TextBox control and a ComboBox control.
Now i want that all the entered information can be view from a second form say ProfilePage of the user.
How can i achieve this as i am new to this technology.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy your question title into google... About 102,000,000 results

Comment: or just look at the related column here on the right

Comment: There are several methods. One is to create a custom clas object inside one form and pass the values to it and later on receive them from the class object in another form.

Comment: @Christos, find another one, this question is `forms` and your link is `wpf`.

Answer (score 0):

IN your Form1 :

```
public static string strForm1 = TextBox1.Text;
```

In your form2 :

```
string strForm2 = Form1.strForm1;
MessageBox.Show(strForm2);
```

Hi, this is only a sample, but you can try this and work around

Comment: why -1? Need also to know.

Comment: Wasn't me, but this is a horrible use of static variables - and it also assumes there is only one `form1`

Answer (score 0):

One way is passing parameters to the new form with the values of the textbox, datetime picker etc..

```
//In your form one
frmSecondForm newForm = new frmSecondForm(this.txtBox.Text, etc...);   //assuming your second form is called frmSecondForm
newForm.Show();



//constructor on the second form
public frmSecondForm(string str, etc...)
{
    this.txtTextBoxOnPage.Text = str;
    etc...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- in first form, write property of the values you want to enter on second form.

**In user registration form:**

```
public DateTime birthday 
{
get{return DateTimePicker1.Value;}
} 
Public string name
{
get {return TextBox1.Text;}
}
Public int IndexCB
{
get {return ComboBox1.SelectedIndex;}
}
```

- in second form, create a constructor which can receive the data you want enter on it.

**In ProfilePage form:**

```
Public ProfilePage (Datetime dt, string n, int i)
{
_birthday = dt;
_name = n;
_indexOfComboBox = i;
}
```

- Now let's pass the information through the two forms.

**on main form (in which you call the user registration form):**

```
UserRegistrationForm urf1 = New UserRegistrationForm();
urf1.Show();
.....
ProfilePageForm ppf1 = New ProfilePageForm(urf1.birthday, urf1.name, urf1.IndexCB);
ppf1.Show();
```

that's how I usually work, hope I've helped you! :) if you still have doubts, write me!